# Find and replace in dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, here are snippets of both below. I am trying to find and replace the artists names in the second dataframe with the id's in the first dataframe. Is there a good way to do this?

```
   id                fullName
0   1           Colin McCahon
1   2  Robert Henry Dickerson
2   3           Arthur Dagley

                                             Artists
0           Arthur Dagley, Colin McCahon, Maria Cruz
1  Fiona Gilmore, Peter Madden, Nicholas Spratt, ...
2                             Robert Henry Dickerson
3                                         Steve Carr
```

Desired output:

```
                                             Artists
0                                   3, 1, Maria Cruz
1  Fiona Gilmore, Peter Madden, Nicholas Spratt, ...
2                                                  2
3                                         Steve Carr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean check with `replace`

```
df1.Artists.replace(dict(zip(df.fullName,df.id.astype(str))),regex=True)
0                                     3, 1, Maria Cruz
1    Fiona Gilmore, Peter Madden, Nicholas Spratt, ...
2                                                    2
3                                           Steve Carr
Name: Artists, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your first dataframe into a dictionary:

```
d = Series(name_df.id.astype(str),index=name_df.fullName).to_dict()
```

Then use `.replace()`:

```
artists_df["Artists"] = artists_df["Artists"].replace(d, regex=True)
```

Comment: That only replaces if, in replace(d), d is the whole string. so, replace("Arthur Dagley","3")) doesnt work.
It would have to be replace("Arthur Dagley, Colin McCahon, Maria Cruz","3, Colin McCahon, Maria Cruz"))